# Add 1 To Every Element in an ndarray if Not Zero

Tags: python, numpy

Python noobie here :)  Trying to figure out how to do things succinctly.

```
>>> f = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=int)
>>> f[0][1] = 100
>>> f[1][0] = 200
>>> print f

[[  0 100]
 [200   0]]

>>> f1 = # do something special
>>> print f1

[[  0 101]
 [201   0]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html). Specifically [masked where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slightly better approach is to use [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0,100],[200,0]])
>>> a[a!=0] += 1
>>> a
array([[  0, 101],
       [201,   0]])
```

The reason it is an improvement is rather well explained on the Matlab fora, where `find` serves a similar role as `np.where`. For example in [this Matlab thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66992-logical-indexing-is-usually-faster-than-find) it is mentioned that `find` is called with an array of booleans. `find` then performs some extra functions to extract the indices. These indices are then used to do what is known as "fancy indexing" in numpy. However, the array itself could've been indexed in this fancy way with the boolean array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to figure out where the value is not 0, then add 1 to all those values.

```
>>> a = np.array([[0,100],[200,0]])
>>> a
array([[  0, 100],
       [200,   0]])

>>> a[np.where(a != 0)] += 1
>>> a
array([[  0, 101],
       [201,   0]])
```